# HTML5 / jQuery Mobile App - Hosting/Updating the content... How to approach this?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Desperate for a helping hand. I've built an App in HTML5/jQuery Mobile. I'm looking to distribute the app through PhoneGap to iOS and Android. As I'm fairly new to app development I have no idea how to approach this next task...

The App is essentially 'offline' when uploaded to PhoneGap (zipped) - however once the App is out there on App stores I would like to update pages in the App.

How do I approach this task?

I would like the majority of the content (headers, footers, logos etc...) to stay offline at all times (Which I assume they will do when sent to App stores?) but update pages, images and even upload newer PDFs?

Do I need to create some sort of Content Management System? Or is there an easier way to do this? I have no problem buying a hosting package etc... I am just clueless at how to handle this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard question to answer. You are going to need to build a json / rest api or possibly use cloud code (parse.com) to update data in your app once it is live on the app store. I'm afraid there are alot of steps involved here so this answer will point you but you have many many days of learning to understand what to do.

Once an app is packaged for apple store it can't be changed unless a new version is uploaded. The dynamic content is provided by an external source.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As silly as it sounds - the phrase 'dynamic content' is what I didn't know. Now I've been able to read and research a lot more into this.